# How to create C++ console application in VS Community 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I installed Visual Studio Community 2015 on Windows 10 64 bit and There weren't much C++ projects, including that one that I really need which is c++ console application.

How can I make C++ console application in VS Community 2015 ?

Comment: Sure ! You have to create win32 app.  You then have the choice btw. windows and console apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File - new - projects - Visual C++ - Win32 - Win32 Console Application.

Comment: Oh! I had made express install on Visual Studio 2015 and it didn't have C++ libraries and projects.

Now I reinstalled it and made custom install and included visual C++. And I have console application.